# How can I connect MultiSig solidity Smart contract with the Safe Protocol?

Tags: solidity, gnosis-safe, multisignature

I have created a MultiSig Smart Contract using solidity and I want to use Safe Protocol here so how can I achieve that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.